# Text to columns for multiple rows

Tags: excel, text, format

Is it possible (using Excel tools, without using VBA) to split following text:

```
Year Month Name 2015 January John 1988 February Samantha 2002 March Jack
```

to make all data be in correct cells?
(i mean 2015, 1988, 2002 under **Year**, January, February, March under **Month** etc.?

```
Year   |  Month      |  Name
===================================
2015   |  January    |  John
1988   |  February   |  Samantha
2002   |  March      |  Jack
```

I tried in **Text To Columns** but it does not seems to be usefull.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by Text To Columns not being useful? What result did it give? Why wasn't that what you were hoping for?

Comment: I am able to separate text into different columns (one word in every column) but the data is still in one row.
I wonder if it's possible to create a rule to start new row for every 3rd entry

Comment: Perhaps you should add your expected results to your post, including cell references to the data, both before and after?

Comment: I've edited my post, so it should be much clearer now.

Comment: So your original text is in a single cell? Is it always to be split after every third space? Could it have more than 12 entries?